# Android custom account manager

Tags: android, accountmanager

I want to create a custom account manager but i don't know which way is the best for this.
Create a new app that will contain the custom account manager and others app just ask for tokken? (In this case how to be sure that this app was install when other app need tokken?) Or maybe just integrate the custom account manager in each app?

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

i found something that is your exact need
follow this link you will find what you need
https://www.fussylogic.co.uk/blog/?p=1031